# how can i implement built-in browser like facebook app

Tags: android

i read article that facebook app has started opening links with its built-in browser
( related article url : http://www.androidcentral.com/facebook-enabling-app-browser-links-some-accounts )

it's quite cool so some apps were updated to use built-in browser.

i also want to develop own built-in browser and use in my app like facebook, but i can't find how to. 
( i searched 'built-in browser', 'in-app browser' etc.. in google, but can't find how to make it. )

so, how can i develop own built-in browser? is there any development guide?

Comment: Start here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a webview. Look this link... If your webpage that you want load is local you must put it in assets and call it with

```
 webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

otherwise like doc

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html